# Can air plasma ions in a fusor fuse?

Tags: air, plasma-physics, fusion, ions, cold-fusion

I know that hydrogen ions will fuse in a fusor but what about air ions? Can air plasma ions in a fusor fuse? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor, if so, under what cicumstances, and how would I replicate it?

Comment: Doesn't the Wikipedia article suggest as much?

Comment: It does say about AIR particles as far as I know...

Comment: - DOES NOT say.

Comment: When you asked about air, you probably meant nitrogen, but I guess that fusors operate anyway in good vacuum conditions so there will not be much air since you would be interested in efficient fusion reactions only, like hydrogen ions (or, to be more precisely, deuterium and tritirum).